# how to perform $this->render() inside symfony2 service?

Tags: php, symfony

I have this code inside a normal symfony2 controller:

```
            $temp = $this->render('BizTVArchiveBundle:ContentTemplate:'.$content[$i]['template'].'/view.html.twig', array(
                'c'=> $content[$i],
                'ordernumber' => 1,
            ));
```

And it works fine.

Now I am trying to move this to a service, but I don't know how to access the equivalent of $this of the normal controller.

I tried injecting the container like this:

```
    $systemContainer = $this->container;

    $temp = $systemContainer->render('BizTVArchiveBundle:ContentTemplate:'.$content[$i]['template'].'/view.html.twig', array(
                'c'=> $content[$i],
                'ordernumber' => 1,
            ));
```

But that didn't work, and I guess that is because render isn't really using the $this->container of the normal controller but only using the $this part.

Anyone know how to use $this->render() from a service?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check method `render` in `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller` class. It says:

```
return $this->container->get('templating')->render($view, $parameters);
```

so since you have container already in your service you can use it like in above example.

NOTE: injecting whole container into service is considered as bad practice, you should inject only templating engine in this case and call `render` method on templating object.

So complete picture:

`services.yml`:

```
services:
    your_service_name:
        class: Acme\YourSeviceClass
        arguments: [@templating]
```

your class:

```
public function __construct($templating)
{ 
    $this->templating = $templating
}
```

and your render call:

```
$this->templating->render($view, $parameters)
```

Comment: note that `$this->templating->render($view, $parameters)` from a service only returns the rendered HTML. symfony needs a full Response object with response headers, HTTP status code, etc. so in a service you need to do something like: `return new Response($this->templating->render($view, $parameters));` this might be obvious to most but was a real gotcha for me as `$this->render` in a controller will wrap the HTML in a response object in the Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php method.

Comment: I have the code as the following structure
src/AppBundle/controller/defaultController
    $body = $this->renderView(''default/index.html.twig',array());
Here I can get the body,
I need the same on 
src/AppBundle/Helper/user/DefaultHelper
how have to call renderView?

Answer (score 6):

Using constructor dependency injection (tested with Symfony 3.4):

```
class MyService
{
    private $templating;

    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        return $this->templating->render('bar/foo.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Comment: In my Symfony 2.8 app I get an instance of Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine injected instead of \Twig_Environment.