# Symfony: how to pass the function render() from a service to a controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a simple service as following:

```
public function showVar($data)
{
    switch($data){
        case 'test':
            return $this->render('test/basic.html.twig', array('var'=>$data));
            break;

        default:
            return $this->render('test/warning.html.twig');
    }
}
```

And loaded it in the controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $var = 'test';

    $locationService = $this->container->get('test');
    $ownFunction = $locationService->showVar($var);

    return $ownFunction;
}
```

This is the error I am getting

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "render" of class
"AppBundle\Service\MyService".
```

I am new to Symfony and I would like to know what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Does your service have a render function ?

Comment: I think the error is pretty clean. Did you define a method named "render"?

Comment: Hi, no I did not define it...how can define it in the service?

Comment: You better use the render inside the controller action

Comment: You could return array('path' => 'path/to/template', 'vars'=>array());  from the service. then in controller $this->render($serviceReturn['path'],$serviceReturn['vars']);   But I think I would recommend injecting twig into your service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your controller needs to return a `Response` Symfony object:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

public function indexAction()
{
    $var = 'test';

    $locationService = $this->container->get('test');
    $ownFunction = $locationService->showVar($var);

    return new Response($ownFunction);
}
```

This is explained in the [Controller chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html) of the Symfony book. The two most common ways to return from a Symfony controller are:

- `new Response($content)`, this is very uncommon but needed when you create the response content by hand.
- `$this->render('templateName', $parameters)`, this is the common case when you return a rendered template.

In your case, the service returns the contents, but rendering a template. The solution then is to inject the `@templating` service in your service and change the code of `showVar()` method by the following:

```
public function showVar($data)
{
    switch($data) {
        case 'test':
            return $this->templating->render('test/basic.html.twig', array('var'=>$data));
            break;

        default:
            return $this->templating->render('test/warning.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Javier, thanks for your answer. I have used your suggestion according to following post: 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909308/how-to-perform-this-render-inside-symfony2-service